# How can I force access my drives?

Tags: nautilus

For example if I have a cd, dvd or pen-drive inserted and the cd/usb icon won't appear in nautilus or in the media folder, how can I access it? Same with floppy drive. Where can I find it and access it after I've inserted a disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]From the Sidebar beside the home folder press Go and go to computer.

Comment: Please provide a more detailed answer and a picture(screenshot) would be better.

Comment: how to upload the pic here ?

Comment: Thanks this really helped. This is a bit confusing though. Where is this "computer:///" in the file system? For example if I need to execute a terminal command how do I navigate there once something is force accessed?

Comment: im sorry because i dont understand what u mean !..im just a beginner

Comment: do u mean how to go to the terminal ? -.-

Comment: I mean how to go there in terminal. If I force accessed a cd or an pen-drive and I need to preform -let's say- a file rescue from terminal, how can I navigate to the force opened cd? Because in "computer" the location of the drives says "computer:///".

Comment: i dont know unfortunately. hmmm after one hour i will go to college and i will ask my teacher about it (Inshaa Allah) .i hope someone here can help u.